Cannot upgrade my Focal (20.04.6) LTS
I have tried to upgrade in several ways.  Most just said I need to upgrade all packages first, but I have already done that.  Over and over.
But synaptic marks a few of them with notations I have not seen before, and remarks about blocked and broken packages.  For starters, when I ask it to list "Installed (upgradable)" it shows four, all with a grayed-out "!" in the checkbox:

gnome-software
gnome-software-common
gnome-software-plugin-snap
ubuntu-software

and in addition, there's two that showed up a couple of times but is not flagged by synaptic

fwupd-singed
fwupd-unsigned

How do I get this system upgraded???

could you run the command line apt (apt update; apt upgrade) and post the output of that?

There is online help in fixing package issues, such as https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ubuntu-fix-broken-packages and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-fix-broken-packages-in-ubuntu . The Synaptic Package Manager also has a menu item to fix broken packages, though not as complete as Terminal use of apt.
